# jQuery DateTime Picker did not work inside AJAX Tab Control

Tags: jquery, ajax, datetimepicker

In my form I have AJAX tab control, inside I have jQuery DateTime Picker.

DateTimePicker is working fine when it is outside AJAX tab control but inside it did not work. The following is my design source. Can anyone help me to get this issue fixed?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
/>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css"
/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $('#txtTimeStarts').datetimepicker({
            ampm: true
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $('#txtDefTimeStarts').datetimepicker({
            ampm: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Body Part :

```
      <asp:UpdatePanel ID ="OfferDeal" runat ="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
             <cc1:Tabcontainer CssClass="Tab" id="TabContainer1" runat="server"  
                  activetabindex="0" AutoPostBack="True" >

 <cc1:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="Define Loyalty Offer" ID="TabPanel1"  >


            <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="createoffer">
              <div class="setup-offer"  style="display:block;">
                <div class="sec-main"><span class="sec-title">Define your offer</span> <span class="note">For example: "Buy 7 coffee drinks and get the next one free" or "Make 10 purchases over $25 and receive 10% off your next purchase"</span>
                  <div class="textareafld">
                    <div class="field">
                      <%--<label for="txtareOffer1" class="infield">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat.</label>--%>
                     <%-- <textarea class="textfield" id="txtF9" ></textarea>--%>

                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtareaOfferDesc" runat="server" CssClass="textfield" 
                            TextMode="MultiLine" ></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="sec-main"><span class="sec-title">Define Offer Validity:</span>
                  <div class="datefld">
                    <label class="name">Offer start date</label>
                    <div class="field">
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtTimeStarts" runat="server" CssClass="textfield"></asp:TextBox>
                         <span class="date"></span>            
                    </div>
                    <span class="error">Error message</span></div>
     </ContentTemplate>

    </cc1:TabPanel>
<cc1:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="Define Deals" ID="TabPanel2" class="pannel_outer">
 <ContentTemplate>
              <div class="setup-offer" style="display:block; border:1px solid #ddd; margin:0px 0 0 3px;">
                <div class="sec-main"><span class="sec-title">Define your Deal</span> <span class="note">For example: "Buy 7 coffee drinks and get the next one free" or "Make 10 purchases over $25 and receive 10% off your next purchase"</span>
                  <div class="textareafld">
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtDefineDeal" runat="server" CssClass="textfield" 
                          TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="sec-main"><span class="sec-title">Define Offer Validity:</span>
                  <div class="datefld">
                    <label class="name">Offer start date</label>
                    <div class="field">
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtDefTimeStarts" runat="server" CssClass="textfield"></asp:TextBox>
                        <span class="date"></span>
                    </div>
                    <span class="error">Error message</span></div>
 </ContentTemplate>
            </cc1:TabPanel>
        </cc1:Tabcontainer>
        </ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Why don't you accept the answers on some of your previous questions. That'll help you get more answers in the future.

Comment: I don't know very well asp, but did you tried to put each <script> inside of each tabpanel? Can this be done?

Comment: Can you post the final results of the code? (SOURCE CODE [=HTML] when running your asp file)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all

Its working by replacing the ID as follows :

```
txtTimeStarts to #Tabcontainer_TabPanel1_txtTimeStarts 
txtTimeEnds to #Tabcontainer_TabPanel2_txtTimeEnds
```

because by default its getting the ajax tab control id as `parentID`